# error while calling phantomjs in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

```
from selenium import webdriver
drive = webdriver.phantomjs(executable_path='D:\python\scrapy\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
url='https://google.com'
drive.get(url)
```

when i run this python program am getting :

```
drive = webdriver.phantomjs(executable_path='D:\python\scrapy\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
```

Error :

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new instance of the **PhantomJS** / **Ghostdriver** is achieved through calling **`webdriver.PhantomJS()`**. So you need to change your code as :

```
from selenium import webdriver

drive = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\python\scrapy\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
url='https://google.com'
drive.get(url)
```